# What's the priority of admission webhook and controller manager in k8s？

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

If I has an admission webhook that denies all deleting requests of secrets. So when i delete a project, what happen to the secrets in that namespace, will they be deleted anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This figure](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/additional_concepts/dynamic_admission_controllers.html) shows where admission controller works.

Note that:

1. By default, the only way to delete k8s resources (ex: secret) is to access k8s api.
2. Admission controller applies to each api call that passes A/A check.

So, secrets will not be deleted.